# New Partial View does not render

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I tried to load a second partial view after I submitted info from my first partial view but on submit, my partial view just refreshes and it says on the same partial view instead of the new one. I'm not sure why since I'm positive I set up my controller actions and razor code to load the partial view correctly. I think it might be with how I'm doing the js but I'm not sure.

Here's the ajax call when I click on submit on the first partial view. On submit, I would like to load the second view:

```
var SubmitInfo = function () {

    var form = $('form#FirstForm');
    var result = form.valid();
    var dataToSerialize = form.serialize();

    if (result) {
        $.ajax({
            url: Url.getFullUrl('Home/FormOneInfo'),
            type: 'Post',
            data: dataToSerialize,
            cache:false,
            success: function (data) {

                LoadFormTwo(data);
            }
        });
    }
    return result;
}

var LoadFormTwo  = function (data) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  Url.getFullUrl("Home/FormTwoInfo"),
        success: function (data) {  }
    });
}
```

Just to be clear, when I call the second ajax method, it goes to my controller action. In my action, I set a bool,DisplayFormTwo, to true and then in my main view with the specific div, I have something like this:

```
<div class="centerDivContent">
               if (Model.DisplayFormOne == true){
                    @Html.Partial("FormOne", new ViewModels.FormOneViewModel())
               else if(Model.DisplayFormTwo == true) {
                    @Html.Partial("FormTwo", new ViewModels.FormTwoViewModel())
               }
         </div>
```

This part does get hit in the debugger but a new view is not rendered.

Comment: How/where do you call `SubmitInfo` ?

Comment: In my first partial view, FormOne, I have a submit button that has an onclick listener. On click, it executes that part of the code.

Comment: that button might be makeing a normal submit of the form  (*and so the page is reloaded*). Do you cancel normal form submission ? Please post the html with the attached js

Comment: Hard to understand what your trying to do here. `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);` is pointless since you have not added any dynamic content at that point. You pass the html (or is it json?) returned by the controllers `FormOneInfo()` to the `LoadFormTwo()` function but never use the data. And then you never do any thing with the data (is it html or json) returned by the controllers `FormTwoInfo()` method.

Comment: And razor code is parsed when the view is first loaded so if the initial value of `Model.DisplayFormTwo` is `false` then your `if else` block is never executed. Making an ajax call does not change that.

Comment: Model.DisplayFormTwo is set to true in the controller, so it is returned to the view as true. I debugged it and it does get hit. That why the page reloads but it reloads to the same old partial view though.

Comment: @Euridice01, You said that `<div class="centerDivContent">` is in the main view which mean that unless its `true` in the controller method that renders the initial view you will never ever hit your `else` block - certainly nothing in your ajax calls could do that. And what do you mean reloads the view? You never do anything with any of the data returned by either of your ajax calls - they are completely pointless. If your reloading te page, its because your doing a normal submit or redirect as well as your ajax calls

Comment: Okay but I'm still confused on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I may be reading this wrong but shouldn't you be putting the data into the container when you call LoadFormTwo

```
success: function (data) { $(someElement).append(data) }
```

Comment: what is someElement supposed to be?

Comment: The container you want your data to go in. For example if you have a container with an id of myID you'd put $("#myID").append(data);

Comment: Well I'm not sure I need that because the ajax calls an action and in that action I set a bool to true and then using razor in the partial view, it set up the new partial view using @html.partial()